# How do I print my application reports

Tags: php, css, mysql, printing

I am working on an application developed with HTML, CSS, PHP and MySQL.
I have developed few student performance reports for endusers where they can choose filters and dates to check the student reports. The reports are displayed on the browser with some performance graphs and pagination.

I want to implement the print functionality for these reports so that enduser can print the report he is viewing on the browser.

Here I need to print all the records not only currently displayed on the browser (because I am using pagination).

Do I have to write the print css?

I want to print the A3 and A4 size pages.

Comment: If you want use the browser Print action, you have to have all records in your html (they dont have to be visible), and in print css you just set them to visible. But that means you have to change your pagination from PHP style to JS only.

Comment: @Autista_z thanks, as of now I am fetching all records and later I will implement the jQuery Grid for pagination. How can I fit the results in A4 size page so that the records gets printed